# Creating a DateTime from UTC seconds

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't believe that I can't find this anywhere, but how can you create a DateTime from UTC seconds? Similar to how in Java you can do `Calendar.getInstance().setTimeInMillis(time)` to get a certain time.

`DateTime.new 1344899588` didn't work, and I don't see anything in the DateTime API docs that shows how to do this.

This works, but seems like a roundabout way to do it:

```
DateTime.strptime(1344899588.to_s, "%s")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Time class for this, i.e.

```
t = Time.at(1344899588)
```

If you need a Date object rather than a Time object, you can do:

```
d = Time.at(1344899588).to_date
```

And, if you need a DateTime object, you can do:

```
dt = Time.at(1344899588).to_datetime
```

Which, btw, yields `Mon, 13 Aug 2012 16:13:08 -0700`